# avoid member move boilerplate in move constructor?

Tags: c++, boilerplate, move-constructor, keyboard-avoidance

Sometimes you still want the default move-constructor behavior (member-wise move), but also want to modify the moved-from object. Take the following scenario, for example

```
class Base{...}; // some move-constructible class
class Member{...}; // also move constructible

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // does member-wise move, but nothing more
    // Derived(Derived &&) = default;

    // does member-wise move, same as default
    // and also modifies `other`
    Derived(Derived && other)
        : a(std::move(other.a))
        , b(std::move(other.b))
        , ... // the rest of members
    {
        other.put_into_invalid_state_or_something();
    }

    //...............................................
    //      More functions
    //...............................................

private:
    // a lot of members...
    Member a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
};
```

This may be a silly question, but is there any way to avoid writing the move for each member?

Comment: "// a lot of members..." this can be a sign of a bad design. Maybe try and group various members into their own classes if it makes logical or semantic sense.

Comment: 1. How do you decide which variable should be invalidate? 2. Why doesn't it invalidate itself?

Comment: You could make `Base` have a `make_invalid`-move constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/aEf449zdY

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? To prevent "use after move"?

Comment: what exactly is `put_into_invalid_state_or_something()` ? After you moved the members the moved from object is already a moved from object. Also moved from objects should be in a valid state, not in an invalid state

Comment: Can't you group member which need/affect `put_into_invalid_state_or_something();` in a dedicated struct? Then only that struct would require special treatment., and your move constructor of `Derived` can then be defaulted.